# python setup.py install 'g++-4.2' failed

Tags: python, gcc, g++

I want to install echonest's remix python library, but I get the following error when I run `python setup.py install`:

```
error: command 'g++-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

When I run `g++ --version`, I get the following:`g++ (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2) 4.7.2`

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Play with `setup.py` file, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a link to `g++`, called `g++-4.2` somewhere in `$PATH`.  If `.` is in your `$PATH`, then:

```
ln -s `which g++` g++-4.2
```

You can also make your own directory, add it to `$PATH`, and put the link there:

```
mkdir -f ~/bin
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
ln -s `which g++` ~/bin/g++-4.2
```

But then every time you open a new Terminal, and you want it to know about the `g++-4.2` you made, you have to rerun `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do I know if `.` is in my `$PATH`? I executed this in the folder where the library is and I get the same error.

Comment: `echo $PATH`.  That defines a list of paths that are searched for executables.  They are separated by `:`.